# how to use digamma function in boost

Tags: c++, boost, numerical

I don't understand how the [digamma function of boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_gamma/digamma.html) can be used inside a program. Any example, is appreciated. I included boost

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/digamma.hpp>
```

but the function call `digamma(x)`, where x is a `double` gives the following error:

> error: there are no arguments to ‘digamma’ that depend on a template
>   parameter, so a declaration of ‘digamma’ must be available
>   [-fpermissive]

Comment: What do you not understand? You just plug in a value and get the documented result, doesn't get easier than that.

Comment: To be more specific, if the function somehow does not work for you, please present your [mcve] so we can see what you are doing wrong / what you are not understanding correctly.

Comment: just edited the question.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, MCVE please. Or did you forget the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:
http://cpp.sh/7bdu

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/digamma.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << boost::math::digamma(3.14) << "\n";
}
```

*edit:* The question was edited with an error message. The error message means that the compiler didn't find a definition of `digamma`, because you didn't include the namespace bit `boost::math::`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Is there a way to define a shorter alias for  `boost::math::digamma()`?

Comment: Yes, you can use the [using directives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives), or [using declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations).